# Liferay Portal hosting on a server

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I've created a liferay portal, and I would like to know how can I host it in a server that we already have in our institution.
please help.

Comment: Choose the appserver you'd like to use and follow the documentation https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide. This question is a bad fit for stackoverflow - too broad and not programming related.

Comment: I'm sorry. but I can't find a documentation about hosting a liferay portal in the link that you have suggested to me.

Comment: "Hosting on a server" means that you're installing the appserver of your choice and then Liferay on top of it. The documentation covers how to install Liferay on several Appservers. Choose one that you're most familiar with and follow the instructions.